# Crawling anonymously with Squid in Python or Shell

Tags: networking, server, python, proxy, tor

I want to browse and crawl anonymously on my squid proxy server, using 10 IP addresses, so each 20 seconds change the IP address automatically. Any idea how exactly this can be done?

I have tried the below code, but it doesn't help out.

```
#!/bin/bash
base_socks_port=9050
base_http_port=3129 # leave 3128 for HAProxy
base_control_port=8118
# Create data directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "data" ]; then
    mkdir "data"
fi
for i in {0..9}
do
    j=$((i+1))
    socks_port=$((base_socks_port+i))
    control_port=$((base_control_port+i))
    http_port=$((base_http_port+i))
    if [ ! -d "data/tor$i" ]; then
        echo "Creating directory data/tor$i"
        mkdir "data/tor$i"
    fi
    # Take into account that authentication for the control port is disabled. Must be used in secure and controlled environments

    echo "Running: tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword \"\" --ControlPort $control_port --PidFile tor$i.pid --SocksPort $socks_port --DataDirectory data/tor$i"

    tor --RunAsDaemon 1 --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort $control_port --PidFile tor$i.pid --SocksPort $socks_port --DataDirectory data/tor$i
    echo    "Running: ./delegate/src/delegated -P$http_port SERVER=http SOCKS=localhost:$socks_port"

    ./delegate/src/delegated -P$http_port SERVER=http SOCKS=localhost:$socks_port
done
haproxy -f rotating-tor-proxies.cfg
```